# Flutter : impossible to edit TextFormField

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield, textformfield

I enconter a strange problem for hours

I have a custom textformfields in my whole app that work fine, but not in one screen. The textfield is initiated with data retrieve from a bluetooth device, but I don't understand why, the textfield cannot be edited manually, by clicking on keyboard. I have no error, only this warning

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
> W/TextInputPlugin( 3071): Changing the content within the the composing region may cause the input method to behave strangely, and is therefore discouraged. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78827 for more details
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3071): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Here a sum up of the screen

```
    class _ConfigurationPageState extends State<ConfigurationPage> {
    late MaintenanceHandlerFeature? maintenanceHandlerFeature;
    StreamSubscription? subscription;
    String appkey = "";  
    final _appkeyController = TextEditingController();

     @override
     void initState() {
       _initParam();
       super.initState();
     }

     @override
     void dispose() {
       subscription?.cancel();
     super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [ TextFormField(
                           controller: _appkeyController,
                           enabled: networkIsActive,
                           context: context,
                           label: 'APPKEY',
                           errorMessage: '',
                           maxLength: 16,
                           validator: (value) {
                             return null;
                           },
                        ),
                     ],
           ));
     }

    void _initParam() async {
      maintenanceHandlerFeature = globals.device.getFeature();
      BluetoothCharacteristic maintenanceCharacteristic =
        maintenanceHandlerFeature!.getCharacteristic();
      await maintenanceHandlerFeature!.activateBluetoothReading();
      subscription = maintenanceCharacteristic.value.listen((List<int> value) {
        _getLoraData(value);
      });
      await maintenanceHandlerFeature!.getAppkey();
      subscription = maintenanceCharacteristic.value.listen((List<int> value) {
        _getData(value);
      });
    }

    _getData(List<int> value) {
      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
        if (value[0] == 0xB2) {
          setState(() {
            appkey = utf8.decode(value.sublist(1, 17), allowMalformed: true);
            _appkeyController.text = appkey;
          });
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If I comment `_appkeyController.text = appkey;` in `_getData`, I can edit but the textfield is not  initiated.
I tried to call `_appkeyController.text = appkey;` outside the setState, but idem
I also tried to add a onChanged function to the textfield but it didn't change anything.

Please help me

Comment: your code sounds like ok but you can try `_appkeyController = TextEditingController(text: appkey);` and check your if statement is ok.

Comment: @JahidulIslam, unfortunately, no change

Comment: check your `if (value[0] == 0xB2) ` and set up log, does it work or not?

Comment: i think that there are too many events coming from maintenanceCharacteristic.value.listen. Maybe UI gets stucked?

Comment: it works. I checked everything possible before posting this question

Comment: @Autocrab, I can receive 3 kinds of data where  value[0] is different. And each value is a list of 17 integers, that's all

Comment: How fast these lists emits? Try to put a delay between each emit and see what happens

Comment: @Autocrab. I put 5 s delay. When `_detData` was called by another value, I could edit the textfield, but as soon as ` setState(() {
            appkey = utf8.decode(value.sublist(1, 17), allowMalformed: true);
            _appkeyController.text = appkey;
          });` is called, impossible :(

Comment: _appkeyController.value= appkey; instead of text?

Comment: @BrandonPillay, with `_appkeyController.value = appkey as TextEditingValue`, I can edit but not init the textfield since there is an error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'TextEditingValue' in type cast`. I tried with `_appkeyController.value = TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: appkey)).value` or `            _appkeyController.value = TextEditingValue(text: appkey)` but still impossible to edit